# How do I upload a file as part of a multipart request in Paw?

Tags: paw-app, rapidapi

I am currently mocking out several endpoints in Paw, including one that would typicaly receive multipart form data as a combination of standard text input as well as a file.

If it were a form, it would look like this:

```
<form action="/image/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="text-stuff" type="text" />
    <input name="image-stuff" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

How do I upload a file as part of a multipart request in Paw?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

And found 5 mins later.

You need to right click on the field, then select "File".

**Link**

**Update Dec 2017**

https://paw.cloud/docs/getting-started/set-request-body#Set_Multipart_body

**Previously**

*As note in the comments, the original link has died*
https://web.archive.org/web/20150326015604/http://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Send_Files_as_Multipart_Form_Data

*Original reference*

https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Send_Files_as_Multipart_Form_Data

Comment: you can also access dynamic values through the auto complete. I you start typing `{fi` you will see the file option in the auto complete menu.

Comment: Ah nice tip matthaus woolard

Comment: Link is dead. Old version: https://web.archive.org/web/20150326015604/http://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Send_Files_as_Multipart_Form_Data

Comment: Here's an updated article about request body and multipart in Paw: https://paw.cloud/docs/getting-started/set-request-body#Set_Multipart_body

Comment: Thanks @MichaMazaheri - love Paw, use it daily!

Comment: .... well... a little button would have been nice. Who is going to right-click everywhere :D thanks for the update; it saved me a lot of time.